# window.Datalayer is undefined during Jest react test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, window, react-testing-library

I started writing tests for a big codebase using Next.js/React + redux with Jest and React Testing Library. Everything works just fine, however my tests fail because the window.dataLayer seems to become undefined during a test. It works fine when running the application normally.

**Error:**

[image]

I already tried mocking it with:

```
jest.spyOn(window.dataLayer, 'push')
.mockImplementation(() => {  })
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given
```

and

```
jest.spyOn(window, 'dataLayer' ,'push')
.mockImplementation(() => {  })
```

**Error:**

```
 dataLayer property does not exist
```

and

```
window.dataLayer = {
  push: jest.fn().mockImplementation(config => {
    config.eventCallback();
  }),
};
```

**Error:**

```
   TypeError: config.eventCallback is not a function
```

within the beforeEach() of the test suite. How can this be solved?

Comment: Why did you call `config.eventCallback()`?